# HTTPS Doesn't Work via IIS Reverse Proxy

Tags: iis, ssl, https, url-rewriting, arr

I have set up a reverse proxy on a Dev box using IIS + ARR + URL Rewrite and everything works as expected with a mix of HTTP and HTTPS URLs.

I took web.config to another server with IIS + ARR + URL Rewrite and pasted web.config under Default Web Site; now I can access HTTP URLs via reverse proxy but HTTPS doesn't work. I made sure the target SSL certificate is trusted and I can access target service in a browser without any SSL issues but I'm not having any luck with the reverse proxy.

I have also matched ARR and URL Rewrite configs on both boxes (and they match) - any idea what I could be missing here - do I need to set up HTTPS binding as well? Also, are there any logs that can help me investigate this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the HTTPS binding on the new server, adding the binding did the trick.